# Accessing parent attributes

Tags: jquery

How to access `href` attribute of parent anchor tag?

```
<a href="#"><li><div class="my-class">Click ME</div></li></a>
```

How do I change href value in jQuery?

I tried this,

```
 $('.my-class').find('li').find('a').attr('href','http://example.com');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write:

```
$('.my-class').closest('a').attr('href','http://example.com');
```

`closest()` traverses up through the DOM tree.

[More information here.](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
 $('.my-class').parent('a').attr('href','http://example.com');
```

REFERENCE

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: `$('.my-class').parent()` will return `li` not `a`.  So it has to be like `$('.my-class').parent().parent().attr('href','http://example.com');` or `$('.my-class').parents('a').attr('href','http://example.com');`  Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Ydt7s/3/) for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the ancestor, find is use to get descendants.

```
 $('.my-class').cloest('a').attr('href','http://example.com');
```

[**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> **Description:** For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing
>   up through its ancestors in the DOM tree, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

[**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

**Description:** Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Answer (score 1):

Try [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.my-class').closest('a').attr('href','http://example.com');
```

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qwjQT/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

`$('.my-class').find('li')` will be looking for `li` element within the `div.my-class`.  Therefore it didn't worked.

Since `a` is the *parent of parent* of the `.my-class` element.

Then try this below code

```
$('.my-class').parents('a').attr('href','http://example.com');
```

or

```
$('.my-class').parent().parent().attr('href','http://example.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/Ydt7s/1/)

Try this

```
  $('.myclass').parents('a').attr('href','http://example.com');
```

Hope this helps ,Thank you